Pydantic v2 model built with datamodel-codegen is failing to load with TypeError: Forward references must evaluate to types
I am trying to build a Pydantic model for the Azure Fabric report page JSON schema which I will then use to validate generated JSON page documents.
Environment:

Linux (Debian bookworm)
Python 3.10.14
Pydantic 2.8.2 via pip install
datamodel-code-generator 0.25.9 via pip install

I curld the schema JSON locally as page.json and ran the command:
$ datamodel-codegen --input page.json --input-file-type jsonschema --output page.py --output-model-type pydantic_v2.BaseModel

Which generated 20,999 lines of code.
I initially tried importing the model to use for validation and got errors, so I simplified my test case and just ran the generated python file which generated the error below (the same errors as when I tried to import the model):
$ python page.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/snip/files/schemas/page.py", line 10432, in <module>
    class QueryDateAddExpression(BaseModel):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 200, in __new__
    set_model_fields(cls, bases, config_wrapper, types_namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 469, in set_model_fields
    fields, class_vars = collect_model_fields(cls, bases, config_wrapper, types_namespace, typevars_map=typevars_map)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_fields.py", line 132, in collect_model_fields
    type_hints = get_cls_type_hints_lenient(cls, types_namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_typing_extra.py", line 228, in get_cls_type_hints_lenient
    hints[name] = eval_type_lenient(value, globalns, localns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_typing_extra.py", line 240, in eval_type_lenient
    return eval_type_backport(value, globalns, localns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_typing_extra.py", line 264, in eval_type_backport
    return typing._eval_type(  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 327, in _eval_type
    return t._evaluate(globalns, localns, recursive_guard)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 693, in _evaluate
    type_ = _type_check(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 176, in _type_check
    raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")
TypeError: Forward references must evaluate to types. Got FieldInfo(annotation=NoneType, required=True, description='Unit of time to add to the date.').

Looking at the QueryDateAddExpression() class that triggered the fault:
class QueryDateAddExpression(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        extra='forbid',
    )
    Amount: float = Field(..., description='Number of units to add to the date.')
    TimeUnit: TimeUnit = Field(..., description='Unit of time to add to the date.')
    Expression: QueryExpressionContainer = Field(
        ..., description='Expression to which to add.'
    )

I can see that the TypeError refers to the TimeUnit() class. I don't think this is a forward reference problem for two reasons:

I'm using from __future__ import annotations which as I understand it, gives me lazy-evaluation.
The TimeUnit() class is defined at line 136 in page.py so has already been parsed by the time it's referenced in the QueryDateAddExpression() class which is at line 10,432 in the same file.

I found a GH issue which seems related.
I'm not super experienced with the internals of Python (yet!) so am a bit stuck at trying to figure this out. I think it's incorrect that the pydantic eval chain is returning the FieldInfo(...), but I'm not sure where to go from here.
I wrote some minimal repro cases to check what happens when I do have a forward reference, and they behave as expected (including testing out ForwardRef()).
I could try converting the generated model to use ForwardRefs and quoting all types as strings, but it's 20 kLoC  and I also think I've proven it's not a forward reference problem.
I would appreciate any help at all! The generated model is posted as a gist here
I was expecting to generate a page.py Pydantic model that I could then import and use to validate candidate JSON, but instead I am getting the TypeError.
As mentioned, I suspect the fault isn't entirely as the error message states. I can't understand why the type check is returning the FieldInfo data.

It's unusual to have caspal-cased attributes and I'm actually surprised that the datamodel-code-generator didn't change it to snake-case. Did you do something to prevent this? Best would be to avoid this naming conflict. But I think in your case you could also get around this by using the --use-annotated flag.
